Problem: Contacts with the Same Name Merged on Android – Notes Field Useless
I’ve been facing an annoying issue on my Android phone when it comes to managing contacts. Whenever I save multiple contacts with the same name (e.g., John), they automatically get merged into one contact. This makes it super difficult to differentiate between them, especially when I need to call or message a specific person.
Even worse, I’ve tried adding notes to the contacts to help distinguish between them, but it doesn’t help. Whenever a new number with the same name is saved, it gets added to the contact with the note, making the notes useless for identifying the contact.
However, when I access my contacts on my laptop or through a browser, everything seems fine. No merging happens, and the contacts remain separate.
Has anyone else experienced this? How can I stop Android from merging contacts with the same name? I’d appreciate any advice on how to fix or work around this issue, as it’s making my contact management a real mess!

As a temporary work-around, I'd suggest using custom label fields for the phone numbers to distinguish them, similar to how you attempted to use the notes field.
